# MVC doesn't return JSON data en error: xhr.responseJSON is undefined

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services

```
  $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: "POST",
        data: parameters,
        success: function (response) {
       ...
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            ...
         //   xhr.responseJSON is undefined here even tho the locally it would

        }
    });
```

After wasting some time , figured out the prob. Include below section in web config and voila.

This also works for Azure.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: did you try using `dataType: "json",`?

Answer (score 0):

the ajax call was working fine locally I just needed to add this to the web config:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```